How do I insert text into a form on a forum?
There is such a form, forum reply. It is huge and I tried to shorten it to show its essence, where there is a quote. There is also a submit button that is not shown.
It is absolutely unclear how to insert text into such a form and where to insert it?
I tried inserting text into textarea name=“message_html”>, but I get ElementNotInteractableException i.e.

Element <textarea name=”message_html“> is not reachable by keyboard.

<form action="/threads/somecoolthread.908787612/add-reply" method="post" class="block js-quickReply" data-xf-init="attachment-manager quick-reply ajax-submit draft" data-draft-url="threads/somecoolthread.908787612/draft" data-draft-autosave="60" data-captcha-context="xf_guest_thread_quick_reply"
data-message-container="div[data-type='post'] .js-replyNewMessageContainer">
    <input type="hidden" name="_xfToken" value="2409434567,26f1433a729b2c456f2617f2e9d8c345a">
    <div class="message-editorWrapper">
        <script class="..." type="...">...</script>
        <div class="fr-box bbWrapper fr-ltr fr-basic fr-top" role="application" data-size="XL">
            <div class="fr-wrapper" dir="ltr" style="max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                <div class="fr-element fr-view fr-element-scroll-visible" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 100px;" aria-disabled="false" spellcheck="true">
                    <blockquote data-quote="Chat" data-source="post: 4567456" data-attributes="member: 35467345">
                        <p>&ZeroWidthSpace;newetherless
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fr-second-toolbar"></div>
        </div>
        <textarea name="message_html" class="input js-editor u-jsOnly" data-xf-init="editor" data-original-name="message" data-buttons-remove="xfInsertGif,xfCustom_parsehtml" style="height: 137px; display: none;" aria-label="Rich text box" data-min-height="100"
        placeholder="Write your reply..." data-deferred="off" data-xf-key="r" data-preview-url="threads/somecoolthread.908787612/reply-preview">&lt;blockquote data-quote="Chat" data-source="post: 4567456" data-attributes="member: 35467345"&gt;&lt;p&gt;General idea&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" value="[QUOTE=&quot;Chat, post: 4567456, member: 35467345&quot;]
General idea
[/QUOTE]" data-bb-code="message">
        <noscript>
            <textarea name="message" class="input" aria-label="Rich text box">[QUOTE=&quot;Chat, post: 4567456, member: 35467345&quot;] General idea [/QUOTE]
            </textarea>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</form>

So, how to insert text into such a form? (I think there will be no problem to click the submit button.)

Will the hidden textarea show up when click something? If not, it might not be the normal process that form creator hope users do. You can still use execute_script and change value of textarea by js, but it might cause unexpected result.
